# How to create random strings JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below create 10 random strings, the idea is to have each string in a 'li'. With what I have, I able to create 10 random 'li', but after the sencond 'li' its a new string but with previous one. Is there a way to fix this?

Ex: This is what I trying to get

String 1

String 2

String 3

.......

The output that im currently getting is

String 1

String 1String 2

String 1String 2String 3

.....

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/73cmb11q/

```js
function names()
{
 var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var name_length = 8;
 var randomName = '';
    
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
    console.log(randomLength);

    for(var j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
     var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
     for(var i=0; i<randomLength; i++)
  {
   var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
   randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname+1);
  } 
  var divName = document.getElementById('names');
     divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
 }

 
}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onClick="names()">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```

Comment: _but after the sencond 'li' its a new string but with previous one_ can you explain what this means and maybe give an example of what you want?

Comment: Moving the `randomName` variable declaration inside the first for loop should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reset the string to "" each time after you append an `li`, so a new string is formed next time and you need to use += while adding innerHTML to your div otherwise you will have only one list as you keep replacing the previous ones.

```js
function names()
{
 var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var name_length = 8;
 var randomName = '';
    
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
    console.log(randomLength);

    for(var j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
     var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
     for(var i=0; i<randomLength; i++)
  {
   var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
   randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname+1);
  } 
  var divName = document.getElementById('names');
     divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
                    randomName = "";
 }

 
}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onClick="names()">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `var randomName = '';` after you first `for` loop, it will reset the previous value before generating new random string

```js
function names()
{
 var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var name_length = 8;
 var randomName = '';
    
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
    console.log(randomLength);

    for(var j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        var randomName = '';
     var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
     for(var i=0; i<randomLength; i++)
  {
   var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
   randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname+1);
  } 
  var divName = document.getElementById('names');
     divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
 }

 
}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onClick="names()">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistakes:

- you do not reset `randomName` each time you should do.
- you do not add each `li` in `divName`, but overwrite its whole content each time.

```js
document.querySelector("#createButton").addEventListener("click",names);

function names()
{
 var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 var name_length = 8;
 var randomName = '';
    
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
    console.log(randomLength);

    for(var j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
     var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4); 
        randomName= ""; //randomName have to be reset before create a new name
     for(var i=0; i<randomLength; i++)
   {
    var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
    randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname+1);
   } 
   var divName = document.getElementById('names');

            // instead of =, += allow you to add randomName to the divName content instead of replacing it.
          divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>'; 
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" id="createButton">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line after print the li -

```
divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
randomName = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're running into has to do with the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of your `randomName` variable. Since that variable is initialized outside of your for loops, each time you add a substring to it, you're actually appending it to your previous string. To fix this in your current code, you can just move `randomName` into your first loop.

Also, you're creating your `randomLength` variable twice (once outside the loop and then on every iteration of your loop). Since the variable is only used to generate a random length string, you can safely remove the outer variable.

```js
 function names() {
  var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var name_length = 8;

  for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {
    var randomName = '';
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4);
  
 for(var i=0; i<randomLength; i++) {
   var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
   randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname+1);
    } 
  
    var divName = document.getElementById('names');
    divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onClick="names()">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73cmb11q/2/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of `randomName` into the first for loop. It's not used in the scope it is declared and needs to be reset each time you generate an `li`.

```js
function names() {
  var txt = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var name_length = 8;
  
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var randomName = '';
    var randomLength = Math.trunc(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4);

    for (var i = 0; i < randomLength; i++) {
      var rname = Math.floor(Math.random() * txt.length);
      randomName += txt.substring(rname, rname + 1);
    }

    var divName = document.getElementById('names');
    divName.innerHTML += '<li>' + randomName + '</li>';
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="randomform">
  <input type="button" value="Create" onClick="names()">
  <input type="text" name="randomfield">
</form>

<ul id="names">
</ul>
```